# Printing elements in a linked list based on a user inputted prefix in C

Tags: c, autocomplete, linked-list

I am currently writing an auto-complete program in C and am in need of some help (yes this is a hw assignment). Basically what the program does is asks the user to input a folder name and then adds all of the directories in that folder into a linked list. The user is then asked to input a prefix and the program will print all of the directories that begin with said prefix. 
My question is how do I implement a function to print out all directories with the prefix?

(i have already created the linked list I just need to print out the directories based on the prefix)

sample output:

```
Enter a folder name: /usr/bin
> zi

Files starting with zi in /usr/bin:
zip
zipcloak
zipgrep
zipinfo
zipnote
zipsplit

> zipc

Files starting with zipc in /usr/bin:
zipcloak
```

## code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <ctype.h>

const int MAX = 125;

//node struct
typedef struct Node{
    //fn length
    char fn[256];
    struct Node *next;
}Node;

//list struct
typedef struct List {
    struct Node *head;


} List;


//constants and functions
char *getNext(DIR *dp);
List *create();
void addElement(List *list, char *v);
void printList(List *list);
void printFIles(List *fn, char prefix);

int main(void) {
    // insert code here...

    //variables
    char dirName[MAX];
    char prefix[MAX];
    int i = 0;
    List *fileNames[26];
    DIR *dp;
    char *fn;
    struct dirent *ep;
    char dir[MAX];


    //enter a directory
    printf("Enter a folder name: ");

    scanf("%s", dirName);
    dp = opendir(dirName);



    for (i =0; i<26; i++) {
        fileNames[i] = create();
    }




    if (dp != NULL)
    {

        while ((ep = readdir (dp)) != NULL) {

            strcpy(dir, ep->d_name);   /* adds to list */
            addElement(fileNames, dir);


        }
        (void) closedir (dp);           /*close the directory */
    }
    else{

        perror ("Couldn't open the directory");

    }

    printf(">");
    while (scanf("%s", prefix)) {
        printf("Files starting with %s in %s \n", prefix, dirName);

    }
    return 0;

}


void addElement(List *list, char *v){
    //adds a node to the top of list
    Node *head = list->head;

    //if the head isnt null push it to the front of the list
    if (head != NULL) {
        Node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(Node));

        strcpy(newnode->fn, v);

        //set the next node equal to the head of the list
        newnode->next = list->head;
        list->head = newnode;
        return;

    }

    Node *current = head;
    Node *next = current->next;
    if (next ==  NULL) {
        current = next;
        next = next->next;
    }


    if(next !=NULL){
        //push to end
        Node *current = list->head;
        Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        strcpy(node->fn, v);
        node ->next = NULL;

        while (current->next == NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }

        if (current) {
            current->next =node;
        } else{
            list->head = node;
        }
        return;
    }

    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    strcpy(node->fn, v);
    current ->next = node;
    node -> next = next;


}

void printList(List *list) {
    Node *current = list->head;
    printf("[");
    //iterate
    while (current != NULL) {

        printf("%s", current->fn);

        if (current->next) {
            printf(",");
        }
        current = current->next;

    }
    printf("]");
}

void printFIles(List *fn, char prefix){

    //    Node *node = list->head;
    //
    //    while (node && ) {
    //        <#statements#>
}



List *create(){
    //allocate memory for the lsit
    List *list = malloc(sizeof(List));
    list->head = NULL;  /*head of list is now null*/
    return list;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  More importantly, please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  We can't see your code — we can't readily help you.  Is your linked list in sorted order?  If so, you can handle the search without necessarily scanning the whole list.  If it is unsorted, you will need to scan the whole list.  Depending on how you've organized the code you haven't shown us, it might be appropriate to use `strncmp()` to find entries that match the prefix.

Comment: updated with code

Comment: There's an awful lot of extraneous blank lines in the code shown.  When I compile, GCC 7.2.0 (run on macOS Sierra 10.12.6) complains about: `addElement(fileNames, dir);` saying `error: passing argument 1 of ‘addElement’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]` and identifying ```note: expected ‘List * {aka struct List *}’ but argument is of type ‘List ** {aka struct List **}’```.  I also get told that `fn` is unused — and of course `printFiles()` isn't implemented so I get errors for the unused parameters.  (It isn't called either — it can be omitted altogether.)

Comment: I apologize, I'm running the code in xcode on my macbook, I was working on the printfiles* function but I'm sure if you comment it out it should compile.

Comment: I found `create()` — I missed copying it.  It was also `printFIles()` (curious capitalization) and not `printList()` that gave the problem.  I updated my comment accordingly.

Comment: Why do you have 26 lists of file names?  Why aren't you indexing by the first character?  What do you do with file names that don't start with a letter?  Are you working case-insensitively?  You don't seem to have coded the search code at all — your main program stops after reading the prefix.  Granted, you need to get the first part working sensibly, but you didn't ask about that.   Note that if your compiler warns, treat it as an error.  When I compile (with GCC, as noted previously), I use: `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes …`.

Comment: If the code doesn't compile cleanly with those options, it isn't ready to be run.  Of course, I've only been coding C for thirty-odd years, so I may have picked up some bad habits en route, but I think I've picked up some good ones too.

Comment: I have 26 lists of filenames for each letter of the alphabet. I was able to put all of the directories into a list however I have not figured a way to search through it yet.

Comment: Your code doesn't show the case-mapping, or indeed the letter-index mapping, necessary.  You need to replace `addElement(fileNames, dir);` with something like `if (isalpha(dir[0]) { int initial = tolower(dir[0]) - 'a'; addElement(fileNames[initial], dir); }` which ignores names not starting with a letter and maps those that do to an index 0..25.

Comment: Thank you I think I have an idea where to go from here now